# Eloquent hasMany Inversion

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have three Eloqent models I would like to relate to each other (Category, Subcategory and Style) in the one-to-many style. The hasMany relationship is working correctly, but the inversion (belongsTo) is not.

The models are Paragon\Products\Category, Paragon\Products\Subcategory and Paragon\Products\Style. The tables look like this:

**Category** Paragon\Products\Category

```
ID    ...
1
2
```

**Subcategory** Paragon\Products\Subcategory

```
ID   Category    ...
1    2
2    2
```

**Style** Paragon\Products\Style

```
ID   Subcategory    ...
1    1
2    1
```

The relationships look like this:

**Category** Paragon\Products\Category

```
public function subcategories() {
    return $this->hasMany('Paragon\Products\Subcategory', 'category');
}
```

**Subcategory** Paragon\Products\Subcategory

```
public function styles() {
    return $this->hasMany('Paragon\Products\Style', 'subcategory');
}

public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Paragon\Products\Category', 'category');
}
```

**Style** Paragon\Products\Style

```
public function subcategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Paragon\Products\Subcategory', 'id', 'subcategory');
}
```

Ideally, I want to be able to call $subcategory->category(); and have an instance of Paragon\Products\Category returned. At the moment when I do this I get an instance of Builder returned. I assume I'm missing some kind of fetch method from my relationship...

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Also, I'd like to be able to get the name of the Subcategory and the Category (both called 'name') using an instance of the Style model. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want

```
$subcategories = $subcategory->with('category') -> get();


foreach ($subcategories  as $row){


}
```

Comment: From here, how do I access properties of the related model?

Comment: @mikekaperys You are wleomce. Simple foreach loop, but that depends on the result you getting from the table. though it is a different question, Ask a a new question and provide sample data.